# TextView shadow destroyed while capture image

Tags: android, textview, shadow

Shadow gets destroyed while capturing image of textview.

I added text shadow programmatically using setShadowLayer.

```
tv.setShadowLayer(20, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

when I capture image using

```
tv.buildDrawingCache(true);
tv.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

and getting bitmap using

```
bitmap = tv.getDrawingCache();
```

Original Image on Screen

[image]

Captured Image

[image]

Also tried to capture parent layout but same result.

Comment: Can check the results by calling `tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);` before `tv.buildDrawingCache(true);`

Comment: @JiTHiN tried, not working.

Comment: Check this [Link]. I hope this will help. [Link]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225515/capture-entire-content-of-edittext-into-a-picture

Comment: Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531858/how-to-make-any-view-to-draw-to-canvas

Comment: This is one of the method to get the picture from view. Apply this method to the Parent view to get the image of children view.

Comment: just add high blur and then image save successfully but shadow is not properly displaying

Comment: I have a feeling a custom frame buffer might help, m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, (int)(width * m_fboScaler), (int)(height * m_fboScaler), false); I will investigate and get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two images is that the original image is produced using a `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` layer. When you set a shadow layer on text using this layer type, the blur is created by the graphics processor on a texture.

See this article on [View layers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#layers) for details.

The captured image on the other hand is created by rendering into a bitmap, which is essentially the same as using `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`. Since the blur is no longer created by the graphics processor, there is no guarantee that it will look the same.

You can experiment with it. Add code to force software rendering:

```
tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
tv.setShadowLayer(20, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

After you do this, the two images will look the same.

If you would like both images to look more like your original image with hardware blur, you can adjust the blur radius:

```
tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
tv.setShadowLayer(8, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
```

If you would like to get results exactly like the original, by capturing a bitmap of the hardware-rendered image, it must be possible but I don't know an easy way. You might have to rewrite the app using OpenGL to get access to the underlying graphics buffers.

Comment: yes, you are right but smoothness is not preserved like image 1. I already implemented this but when i increase blur its become like image 2 before capturing and when i save image its result is same but not contain smoothness of the shadow.

Answer (score 1):

After creating bitmap call this

```
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

after this

```
bitmap = tv.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code it save what actually appears on the screen.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textView.getWidth(), textView.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            textView.draw(canvas);
            FileOutputStream var5;
            try {
                var5 = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"temp.png"));
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, var5);
                var5.flush();
                var5.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have successfully tested.

Comment: image save successfully but shadow is not properly displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Capture screen in bitmap and then save it.

```
View screen = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screen.getDrawingCache());
screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn on Android HW accelerations (by adding to the manifest `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`)
2. Set a View to layer type LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null)`.

Try with this two things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView textView;
private ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Your text view
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    textView.setShadowLayer(20, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);

    //Get bitmap from textView
    Bitmap customViewBitmap = createDrawableFromView(this, textView);


    //Set the bitmap to imageView
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(customViewBitmap);
}


public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}


/* activity_main.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.pansapp.swipecard.MainActivity">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it but you need root or another source of screenshots. Here is java code:

```
private TextView mTextView;
private ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
    mTextView.setShadowLayer(20, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getViewBitmap(mTextView);

    if (bitmap != null) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

private int getRelativeLeft(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getLeft();
    else
        return myView.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) myView.getParent());
}

private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getTop();
    else
        return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
}

private Bitmap getViewBitmap(View view) {
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "/system/bin/screencap -p"});

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(proc.getInputStream());

        String s;
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("log", s);
        }

        if (bitmap != null) {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,
                    getRelativeLeft(view), getRelativeTop(view),
                    view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
        }

        return bitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using internal `screencap` to get screenshot but it requires root. Google made a library to take screenshots without root, so, you can use [it](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/).

Answer (score 0):

you can save any View as image in this way

```
   try {

    Bitmap mNewSaving = getBitmap(tv);
    String save_file = new File(dir, "View_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

    FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(save_file);
    mNewSaving.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, mFileOutputStream);

    mFileOutputStream.flush();
    mFileOutputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.v("hetal", "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.v("hetal", "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This (long) answer addresses the problems with hardware rendering and capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462944/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-other-app-programmatically-without-root-permission)
"Remember on Android that the graphics are composited on the GPU. So there's no reason why the CPU should have access to a copy of the full composited screen image, and it often doesn't." So we have to resort to screen capture code.
This problem is shown here:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
```

`view.draw` must use `View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, so will not work.

A better attempt is this (but does not work like the others):

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
 view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
 view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    //    Enabling the drawing cache is similar to setting a layer when hardware acceleration is turned off.
    //    When hardware acceleration is turned on,
    //    enabling the drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system
    //    uses a different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag.
         view.buildDrawingCache();
         Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();//note no canvas, or draw
            // copy this bitmap otherwise destroying the cache will destroy
            // the bitmap for the referencing drawable and you'll not
            // get the captured view
         Bitmap bitmap = b1.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
         view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

"If you've got root, you by definition have all Android permissions and can therefore call `captureScreen` API to get a correct image."

One of the new APIs introduced in Android 5.0 is the [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html)  API. According to official documentation this API gives us the ability to capture screen content (without root).

Handy hint :
After Android 4.0 "Ice Cream Sandwich" almost all phones have screen capture via "power off + volume down" button pressed together.

Answer (score 0):

```
tv.buildDrawingCache(true);
tv.setDrawingCacheQuality(View. DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the hardware buffer uses if we supply a Bitmap to the canvas.

1)Override Textview and create your own CustomTextview
2) Override the onMeasure and store width and height of Textview.
3)create a Bitmap of the size of the Textview you can get the Width and height from the onMeasure. 
4) override the onDraw(canvas) - canvas.setBitmap(bitmap) and call super.ondraw()

the data is written onto your Bitmap,check the content