# How to take screenshot fragment (hidden) at android

Tags: android

I create application have 4 tabbar use frament
- Frament A
- Frament B
- Frament C
- Frament D

Now, I was standing in a screen D and I want take screenshot B.

Comment: is the fragment B visible?

Comment: yes, the fragment B visible

Comment: This might work:-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189809/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-view-without-showing-the-view