# How to take screenshot of an activity which is having a scrollview that contains invisible parts

Tags: android, android-activity, screenshot, android-scrollview

I want to take a screenshot of an activity which is having a scrolview.
I am able to take a screenshot that contains only the visible part. Is there a way to take a more complete screenshot of the scrollview so as invisible parts are also included?

Please I need help on this, I have been stuck on it from days.

I've already tried some ways/solutions provided in related questions from the site but none of them worked for me.

Here is the layout I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/capture_screen_shot"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take ScreenShot" />


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sc">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/m">

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Data" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Help me please :)

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189809/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-view-without-showing-the-view) helps

Comment: In your searching did you see [Is it possible to take a screenshot of a view, without showing the view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189809/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-view-without-showing-the-view)?

Comment: changed the title and the language used to make the question more correct and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is work for you.. source [here](https://programmingcode4life.blogspot.my/2016/10/convert-layout-view-to-image-and-store.html).

This is not technically a android screenshot code. but this code is to convert the whole layout view into bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromView(scrollview, scrollview.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), scrollview.getChildAt(0).getWidth());

//create bitmap from the ScrollView 
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int height, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're likley going to need something third party as I don't believe Android has this as a built in functionality.

Check this article out:
http://phandroid.com/2016/07/13/scrolling-screenshots-android/

Pasted important parts:

> Download and install Stitch & Share from Google Play
>
> Using your device’s unique button combination, capture the first
>   screenshot
>
> Scroll down within the app, keeping a small portion of what was in the
>   first screenshot visible and capture the next screenshot
>
> Repeat the previous step until you have captured everything you want
>   to appear within the screenshot
>
> Swipe down on your notification panel and tap the Stitch & Share
>   notification
>
> Tap the green arrow icon in the bottom right corner to save or share
>   your screenshot