# Create bitmap from Worker

Tags: android, bitmap

As we know, we can create bitmap from `View`. But is it possible to create bitmap on background class like `WorkManager`'s `Worker`?

My requirement is, I have to show notification with image on daily basis, this image will generated on background with dynamic data. For this I have a `Layout` with `TextView`s, I tried to bind data to this `TextView`s and then converted this layout as bitmap, but it creates empty bitmap.

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: If you have `Context` for inflater then you can try [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189809/is-it-possible-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-view-without-showing-the-view).. I am not sure about it though..

Comment: @ADM This method is working only on foreground, in background initially it says `To create bitmap, width and height should not be zero, so I fixed the size in layout, then it creates empty bitmap.

Comment: @Gunaseelan can you not just use a custom layout in notification which has a textview and then just add text to textview. Do you want the image only?

Comment: @Raghunandan If it is image than I can share/save.

Comment: not sure if this helps. try inflating a custom imageview in notification and then draw dynamic text on that. not sure. but this off the top of my head. If you find a better way pls do share that as answer. will help a lot