# How to create an image from xml or composable without rendering?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-text

I need to create an image as per user input but without rendering the UI.

I know there is a way to render an image by inflating xml file and rendering on the UI or creating view programmatically without rendering.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527902

[Android take screenshot via code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5939987)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805831

However, is there a way to generate an image from xml without inflating or composable without rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show something on the `UI`, it should be rendered first - with no exceptions. By the `UI` I mean any visual representation of your code - it doesn't matter either presented as an app view or just some image.

You can make inflation invisible to the user and render it silently if you don't want the user to see it before some event, but you still must render it. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26197623/9248201) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582865/9248201).

[Official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws) about the stuff;

I don't know if the info above is helpful but the answer to your question - you have to render to see(show) something.

Comment: Thanks for xml inflate solution, I was able to findviewby ids and set values, and create png file. Is there a similar solution for composable?

Comment: Yep. Just add needed composable to your xml file(they are interoperable) and inflate xml.